# map concrete types which implements interface using nhibernate mapping by code

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want to map one to many collection using nhibernate by code

```
..
   Bag(x => x.Articles,
     c => {  },
     r => { r.OneToMany(); }
   );
```

Articles is `IList<IArticle>` and lets say that I have concrete objects (`MyArticle` and `MyArticle2`) which implements IArticle.

Since I'm getting error `{"Association references unmapped class: MyApp.Model.IArticle"}` I suppose I have to list concrete types which I want to map.

How can I do this?

Update:
To improve clarity I will further describe Article classes. There is

- IArticle (interface)
- ArticleBase (abstract class)
- ArticleX
- ArticleY
- Article...

  public abstract class ArticleBase : Entity, IArticle
      {
         ...
      }

  ```
  public class ArticleX : ArticleBase
  {
     public IList<Image> Images {get; set;}
     ...
  }
  public class ArticleY : ArticleBase
  {
     public IList<Image> Images {get;set;}
     ...
  }
  ```

there is also Image class. Every article has bag of images and image has one to many relation to article.

```
public class Image : Entity<Guid>
{
   public virtual IArticle Article {get; set;}
}
```

**

> Update 2

```
public class Image : Entity<Guid>
{
   public virtual ArticleBase Article { get; set; }
   public Image() { }
}
```

**
I mapped using approach suggested bellow like this

```
public class ArticleBaseMap : ClassMapping<ArticleBase>
    {
        public ArticleBaseMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));

            Discriminator(x =>
            {
                x.Column("discriminator");
            });
        }
    }

public class MyArticleMap : SubclassMapping<MyArticle>
{
    public MyArticle()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("MyArticle");
    }
}

public class ImageMap : ClassMapping<Image>
{
    public ImageMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));
        ManyToOne(x => x.Article, m =>
        {
            m.NotNullable(true);
            m.Class(typeof(ArticleBase));
        });
    }
}
```

I'm getting System.TypeInitializationException with message

```
{"Could not compile the mapping document: mapping_by_code"}
{"Cannot extend unmapped class: MyApp.Model.Article.MyArticle"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work in general. It could work only in case, that we've mapped the `interface` *(acting as abstract class in fact)* already, e.g.: [8.1.1. Table per class hierarchy](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-tableperclass), An example:

```
<class name="IArticle" table="Articles">
    ...
    <discriminator column="Discriminator" />
    <subclass name="Article1" discriminator-value="Article1">
    ...
```

The [Mapping-by-Code - inheritance](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-inheritance.html):

```
public class ArticleBaseMap : ClassMapping<IArticle>
{
    public ArticleBaseMap()
    {
        Discriminator(x =>
        {
            x.Column("discriminator");
```

subclasses:

```
public class Article1Map : SubclassMapping<Article1>
{
    public Article1Map()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("Article1");
...
```

Such a mapped hierarchy should not throw *"Association references unmapped"* any more. So, the mapping in this case, will require the referenced `interface` or abstract/base class to **be mapped** - as hierarchy.

I would suggest, for clarity, to map the **abstract** class, to avoid confusion (that any implementation of `IArticle` can be added to that `Bag`). In fact, I do not see any advantage of mapping *interfaces* from the Buisness domain entities perspective.

Comment: thanks, I've updated my question example code. Can you please take time to reavaluate my posted code and suggest better solution and based on that solution mapping example.

Comment: My view: first of all, the `Image` should for sure reference the ArticleAbstract. This way, NHibernate (and you as well ;) will know, which Article it is, because the ID will be directly belonging to the row with some concrete Discriminator. So try to use `public virtual ArticleBase Article {get; set;}`, map the `ArticleBase` and its hierarchy as I suggested, and all should start to work.

Comment: please take look at this second update. I'm getting System.TypeInitializationException

Comment: Please, try to move the  `MyArticleMap` into the `ArticleBaseMap`. See my link in the answer...

Comment: Check this part from the menitoned article: **An important thing to remember** when mapping inheritance using mapping-by-code is that **when registering our mappings** we should **not** look for `ClassMapping<T>` inheritors **only** - E.g. `SubclassMapping<T>`... do not inherit from `ClassMapping<T>`. The solution I'm using is to look for all implementations of **`IPropertyContainerMapper<T>`**